# LLVM Issues with setting up a Function Pass - namespace issues

Tags: c++, header

I've been coming to this site off and on for a few years, and today I finally ask my first question.  I've been stuck for about a week on this, and am just not good enough at C++ (or have just gone in circles one too many times) to figure this out on my own.

I am using the LLVM compiler infrastructure, and am setting up a Function Pass.  I have done this all before, but I am trying to write it in such a way to enable AliasAnalysis, which has required me to restructure the pass.  This is where I'm getting stuck.

The pass calls upon a variety of methods and data structures located within 6 distinct files.  Each file corresponds to the contents of a struct listed in the header file.

The runOnFunction method for the pass is located in RelRecovery.cpp, the 'main' file for this pass, with other files providing supporting methods and data structures.  The issue is that I need to have the contents of RelRecovery spelled out in the header file so the other methods can use it, but doing so causes a previous definition of 'struct RelRecovery' error when I try to compile everything, since the struct is also defined within RelRecovery.cpp.

In addition, the macros I am using within RelRecovery.cpp to initialize my pass and allow it to use memory dependence profiling information are located at the very end of the file and call a pass-specific initialization method which I get an error of: ‘void llvm::initializeRelRecoveryPass(llvm::PassRegistry&)’ should have been declared inside ‘llvm’.  When I modify the appropriate file in llvm and try to build, I get this error:

```
In file included from /x/grwright/llvm/llvm-2.9/tools/opt/opt.cpp:40:
/x/grwright/llvm/llvm-2.9/include/llvm/LinkAllPasses.h: In constructor ‘<unnamed>::ForcePassLinking::ForcePassLinking()’:
/x/grwright/llvm/llvm-2.9/include/llvm/LinkAllPasses.h:152: error: ‘createRelRecoveryPass’ is not a member of ‘llvm’
```

Here is a brief overview of how the project structure is laid out.

RelRecovery.h:

```
using namespace llvm;
//stuff
struct RelRecovery : public FunctionPass {
public:
  static char ID; // Pass identification, replacement for typeid
  RelRecovery() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

  virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &M);
  virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const;
  virtual bool doInitialization(Module &M);

  //lots of statics for data structures, etc
};

struct RelTrace {
public:
  //struct variables and functions
  RelTrace();
};

//other structs here
```

RelRecovery.cpp:

```
using namespace llvm;
struct RelRecovery: public FunctionPass {
    static char ID;
    RelRecovery() : FunctionPass(ID){
            initializeRelRecoveryPass(*PassRegistry::getPassRegistry());
    }

    //global static variables
    //datastructures
    //methods
};
//static definitions such as:
double RelRecovery::totStaticInstrs = 0.0;

char RelRecovery::ID = 0;
FunctionPass *createRelRecoveryPass() {
    return new RelRecovery();
}

INITIALIZE_PASS_BEGIN(RelRecovery, "relRecovery", "...", false, false)
INITIALIZE_AG_DEPENDENCY(AliasAnalysis)
INITIALIZE_PASS_END(RelRecovery, "relRecovery", "Reliability transformation for     lightweight recovery", false, false)
```

RelOTHER.cpp ...

```
//Constructors and methods and such...
```

So, while the LinkAppPasses.h file error is annoying, what I'd really like to solve first is this error:

```
RelRecovery.cpp:49: error: redefinition of ‘struct RelRecovery’
/x/grwright/llvm/llvm-sfi/RelRecovery/include/RelRecovery.h:67: error: previous     definition of ‘struct RelRecovery’
```

How do I maintain the proper functionality of my pass and all of its files while just defining struct RelRecovery in one place?  I realize I've likely made many, many, MANY stupid mistakes here, but I'm a hardware guy, and programming (especially C++) is not my strong suit.  Sorry, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This seems not to be related to LLVM in any way. You're definitely defining your class twice - one in .h and another one - inside .cpp.

So, inside .cpp you should provide out of line definition of all the methods declared in the .h. In your case for constructor it will be something like this:

```
RelRecovery::RelRecovery() : FunctionPass(ID) {
    initializeRelRecoveryPass(*PassRegistry::getPassRegistry());
}
```